# CoffeeScript prototype error

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
User = (name,dob,rank,score) -> 
    {
        name: name
        dob: dob
        details: {
            rank: rank
            score:score 
        }

        basicInfo: -> return "Name: #{@name} - Dob: #{@dob} - #{@details.rank} "
        detailedInfo: -> return "Name: #{@name} - Rank: #{@details.rank} - Score: #{@details.score}"
    }

User::displayName = ->
    console.log @name 

bob = new User("Bob","10/12/69",1,100000)

bob.displayName()
```

I'm getting an error that says "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'displayName'"

Not really sure why I'm getting this error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not well versed in CFS, but that's not how you declare classes in it. See: http://coffeescript.org/#classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you return a new object from the constructor, it doesn't share the prototype. A proper constructor adds properties/methods to `this`:

```
User = (name,dob,rank,score) -> 
  @name = name
  @dob = dob
  @details =
    rank: rank
    score: score 
  @basicInfo = -> return "Name: #{@name} - Dob: #{@dob} - #{@details.rank} "
  @detailedInfo = -> return "Name: #{@name} - Rank: #{@details.rank} - Score: #{@details.score}"
```

You might want to take advantage of CoffeeScript's `class` abstraction, which just generates standard constructor functions:

```
class User
  constructor: (name, dob, rank, score) ->
    @name = name
    @dob = dob
    @details:
      rank: rank
      score: score 
  basicInfo: ->
    return "Name: #{@name} - Dob: #{@dob} - #{@details.rank} "
  detailedInfo: ->
    return "Name: #{@name} - Rank: #{@details.rank} - Score: #{@details.score}"
```

This is functionally the same as above, except that `basicInfo` and `detailedInfo` here are already in the `prototype`, where they should be. With this, `User::displayName = -> console.log @name` should work fine.

See http://coffeescript.org/#classes

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to copy javascript in coffeescript. Badly.  (By mixing static methods and prototype methods.)

In CoffeeScript, you can use the keyword `class` to do what you want.

```
class User
    constructor: (@name, @dob) ->

    displayName: ->
        console.log @name

bob = new User "Bob", "10/12/69"

bob.displayName() // "Bob"
```

More information: http://coffeescript.org/#classes

Comment: you usually have to learn *more* about javascript to use coffeescript correctly. This question has nothing do to with CS vs JS, but a misunderstanding of how constructor functions work.

Comment: Fair enough, so why would this syntax be used "User::displayName ->"

Comment: @rai See Ricardo's answer, it should actually be the accepted answer.

Comment: @RicardoTomasi fair enough, I'm deleting this troll sentence :)